# internet blocked by filter software even after it is uninstalled

Tags: networking

I have previously installed a web filter which comes with a program that blocks the computer from connecting without their filtered network.
Now I have already uninstalled the filter and deleted this program but when I try to surf it says the internet is blocked.

I can ping websites from the cmd but the browser won't work.
I tried turning off windows firewall but that doesn't help.
Is there a way to tell what is blocking it.
I imagine it is something left over from the internet filter but cannot figure out what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason is that filter software is not be completely uninstalled. You might need to contact the vendor of the filter software to confirm if there is any removal tool can remove all files associated with filter software correctly and thoroughly.